# Looping through pixels in pictures

Tags: c, arrays, swift

I have written the following function:

```
    class func convertImageToBlackAndWhite(#data:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>, inputWidth:UInt32, inputHeight:UInt32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32> {
    var currentPixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>()
    currentPixel = data

    for (var i = 0; i < Int(inputHeight); i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < Int(inputWidth); j++) {
            var color:UInt32 = currentPixel.memory

            // Average of RGB = greyscale
            var averageColor:UInt32 = (R(color) + G(color) + B(color)) / 3
            var updatedColor:UInt32 = RGBAMake(averageColor, g: averageColor, b: averageColor, a: A(color))
            currentPixel.memory = updatedColor
            currentPixel++
        }
    }

    var outputData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>((calloc(UInt(inputHeight*inputWidth), UInt(sizeof(UInt32)))))
    outputData = currentPixel
    return outputData
}
```

I want to return the outputData to display it on screen. Therefore I created within another function this code:

```
    class func processUsingPixels(#inputImage:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    var inputCGImage:CGImageRef = inputImage.CGImage
    var colorSpace:CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var inputWidth:UInt = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage)
    var inputHeight:UInt = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage)
    var bytesPerPixel:UInt = 4
    var bitsPerComponent:UInt = 8
    var inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

    let inputPixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(calloc(UInt(inputHeight*inputWidth), UInt(sizeof(UInt32))))

    var outputData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>()
    outputData = self.convertImageToBlackAndWhite(data: inputPixels, inputWidth: UInt32(inputWidth), inputHeight: UInt32(inputHeight))


    let context:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(outputData, inputWidth, inputHeight, bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(inputWidth), CGFloat(inputHeight)), inputCGImage)


    return inputImage
}
```

The outputData was the data I wanted now to display. I expected that the changes by the for-loop in "ConvertImageToBlackAndWhite" would be reflected, but no change at all happens.

Thanks to Rob I got some valuable insights before. but still this picture does not change at all.

my questions would be:

1) is it correct to create this output data var as a return value? Does it make sense at all?

2) I use this outputData Variable that has been returned to create a Context and Draw the context. But this has no effect. Do I need to create a new Image first? The return value of  processusingPixels is an UIImage. But I thought the CGContextDrawImage would be sufficient. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are initializing `currentPixel` inside the `for` loops. Do that before you start the loops, e.g.:

```
var currentPixel = inputPixels

for row in 0 ..< inputHeight {
    for column in 0 ..< inputWidth {
        var color: UInt32 = currentPixel.memory
        print(String(format:"%X", color))
        currentPixel++
    }
}
```

---

When you're done, you can create new image using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`:

```
func processUsingPixels(inputImage inputImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let inputCGImage = inputImage.CGImage
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let width = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage)
    let height = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage)
    let bytesPerPixel: UInt = 4
    let bitsPerComponent: UInt = 8
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue

    let context:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), inputCGImage)

    let pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))

    var currentPixel = pixelBuffer

    for row in 0 ..< inputHeight {
        for column in 0 ..< inputWidth {
            currentPixel.memory = grayScaleFromColor(currentPixel.memory)
            currentPixel++
        }
    }

    let outputCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    return UIImage(CGImage: outputCGImage)!
}

func grayScaleFromColor(color: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
    let r = Double(red(color))
    let g = Double(green(color))
    let b = Double(blue(color))
    let a = alpha(color)

    let gray = UInt8(0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)

    return rgba(red: gray, green: gray, blue: gray, alpha: a)
}
```

Note, I removed `calloc` from the above. If you keep that in your routine, make sure to `free` it.

---

Implicit in the original question were functions to extract RGBA values from the `UInt32` color, and also to create a color from the RGBA values. For the sake of completeness, I'll include some sample renditions:

```
func red(color: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8(color & 255)
}

func green(color: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8((color >> 8) & 255)
}

func blue(color: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8((color >> 16) & 255)
}

func alpha(color: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8((color >> 24) & 255)
}

func rgba(#red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) -> UInt32 {
    return UInt32(red) | (UInt32(green) << 8) | (UInt32(blue) << 16) | (UInt32(alpha) << 24)
}
```

Personally, I don't really like playing around with this shifting of bits, so I'd naturally be inclined to use a `struct` (like I did [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685598/creating-uiimage-from-nsdata-created-from-buffer-returns-nil/26686111#26686111); that used `PremultipliedFirst` rather than the `PremultipliedLast` used in the question here, but the concept would be the same). But access/manipulate the buffer any way you want.

Comment: One more question if I may ask: I defined color as UInt32. When I log the value it is a negative one. isn't it supposed to be positive?

Comment: It must be how you're logging it. When I log it, it's an unsigned positive number. As you'll see above, I think it's more useful to look at it in hex (so you can glance at it and see the A, R, G, and B values really easily. But if you accidentally logged it as a signed integer, it would appear to be negative because the alpha channel is likely `0xff`, meaning that the high bit is on, and with signed integers, that designates negative number.

Comment: gosh you are right... Thank you Rob. Now when I have a look at this and I would like to change the color of a pixel. Then I would write the following right now:
`var averageColor:UInt32 = (R(color) + G(color) + B(color)) / 3
currentPixel.memory = RGBAMake(averageColor, g: averageColor, b: averageColor, a: A(color))`
I am a little bit irritated that I can't assign the new average color to the currentPixel. I thought the memory function would give me this option. How do I need to do this in SWIFT then?

Comment: You can update the memory (e.g. `currentPixel.memory = updatedColor`) fine. You must be doing something wrong. (By the way, if you're trying to convert to grayscale, you might not want a simple average. I've always used something like `0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue`.)

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you. I edited my question so you see my full code I used. I was expecting to see the new picture as an output. But nothing happens. It does not even crash! Just shows the old picture I selected from the library

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised it doesn't crash. There are serious problems there. You're also leaking your `calloc`ed buffer, too. The reason you're seeing anything at the end is that you're re-drawing the original input image to the output (which is why you're not seeing your B&W image). Anyway, see my revised answer which illustrates one way to manipulate pixel buffer and create new image.

Comment: Thank you Rob! This was amazing! I am pretty much unsatisfied that I didn't see the thing with the context by myself... The dropping of calloc was something I didn't know would be better. But it seems pretty much reasonable. Very good approach. Thank you so much for your support! It runs perfectly smooth

Comment: when i use rgba(red: gray, green: gray, blue: gray, alpha: a) I get 'unresolved identifier rgba'. I have imported CoreGraphics and CoreImage and CoreFramework. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @TimWhiting No, they are functions you have to implement yourself. The OP referenced similar functions in the question, so I didn't see any need to include them in my answer, but for the sake of completeness, I've modified my answer to show what they might look like.

Comment: @Rob thanks, that is now working for me. It takes a good ten seconds to render an image of pretty typical dimensions (2000*1300) using 100% of the cpu. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Depends upon what you're testing it on and your build settings. I just did debug build 2880x1800 image in 0.9 seconds on simulator on my MacBook, but took 5.9 seconds on iPad Air. That changed to 0.4 and 1.2 seconds respectively with release build. If you want to make it even faster, don't manipulate pixels yourself, but rather just use `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()`, 1 byte per pixel, no alpha channel, and that's further improved to 0.2 and 0.3, respectively. If you have further questions, I'd suggest you post your own question.