# Get RGB value of pixel in CGContext iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, rgb, cgimage

I am trying to do a very simple map of an image from one UIImageView to another UIImageView, but via a CGContext, so that I can manipulate the pixel RGB Values. This is the code I have used which allows me to go through the pixels of the initial image and create the output image, but I don't know how to extract the pixel RBG value as I go. Can anyone suggest how?

```
var sampleImage = UIImage()

func map(){
    self.sampleImage = imageViewInput.image!
    var imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sampleImage.size.width, self.sampleImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sampleImage.size)
    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, sampleImage.CGImage)

    var pixelCount = 0
    for var i = CGFloat(0); i<sampleImage.size.width; i++ {
        for var j = CGFloat(0); j<sampleImage.size.height; j++ {

            pixelCount++
            var index = pixelCount

            var red: CGFloat = // Get the red component value of the pixel
            var green: CGFloat = // Get the green component value of the pixel
            var blue: CGFloat = // Get the blue component value of the pixel

            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, red, green, blue, 1)
            CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(i, j, 1, 1))

        }
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    var img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    imageViewOutput.image = img

}
```

Comment: If you are able to get the CGColor of the pixel you can use CGColorGetComponents to get the rgb values from it.

Comment: See Apple [Technical Q&A 1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html). Bottom line, create a context, draw your image to that context, use `CGBitmapContextGetData` to access the pixel buffer. You can then create new image from that pixel data. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28799895/1271826 for Swift example.