# Swift Image Syntax

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uiimage

I've been looking around on the "proper" way to programmatically create an image in Swift and I've found tons of different ways to do it. What is the official way to do it?

Comment: There isn't one, there aren't any official docs for that

Comment: Then what do you suggest?

Comment: Just use one of those ways to do it. You said yourself that you found tons of em, so you certainly don't need another answer ;)

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering if there is a certain official way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no singular "official" way, and there are a variety of different techniques of increasing complexity. The easiest way is generally:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, 0)
// draw stuff
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

If you want to create an image pixel-by-pixel, the process is a little more complicated, as illustrated here: [Looping through pixels in pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799701/1271826).